# Azure Functions with NCrontab returning method not found message

Tags: cron, azure-functions

We are trying to use the NCrontab package to create a new Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.CronSchedule object instance.
Using the following code:

```
    [FunctionName("FunctionTest")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // using NCrontab;
        var nCrontabSchedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("5 4 * * *");

        //using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers;
        CronSchedule cronSchedule  = new CronSchedule(nCrontabSchedule);

        return new OkObjectResult("Hey There");
    }
```

All the packages were recognized and we don't have any build errors.
But, when we try to execute this function through HTTP endpoint, the following error is returned:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. FunctionApp1: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.CronSchedule..ctor(NCrontab.CrontabSchedule)'
```

We saw that the function emulator app uses two different DLL's regarding NCronTab dependency, so we believe that is related to this error.

Here is the single NuGet package that we are using:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
```

Has anyone ever seen the same error before?

Thanks,
Renato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we use [Cronos](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cronos/) instead?

```
       [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        CronExpression nCrontabSchedule = CronExpression.Parse("5 4 * * *");
        DateTime? next = nCrontabSchedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

You may look into [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos#adding-seconds-to-an-expression) for different operations such as get occurrences within range ( e.g. for an year) or working with the local times. Will it suffice the requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We decided to change our implementation instead of using a 
Schedule constructor. But, definitely, we will take a look at this lib. We saw the benchmark and we liked it. Thanks again.